# The connection "C:\\<path>\\*.txt" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific conn element is not found

Tags: ssis

I developed a SSIS package that creates several .txt files. These files are zipped and then the .txt files need to be removed. Using a foreach file enumerator, I loop through all the .txt files for a specific folder. The folder is retrieved from a variable in configuration and looks something like: C:\Folder\

The foreach loop uses: *.txt to gather all .txt files, does not traverse subfolder and uses the full qualified name.

In the Variable Mappings the "FileName" variable gets filled with the 0 index.
Within the foreachloop I use a File system task. 
This task removes the .txt files which are generated before, using the FileName variable that is filled in the loop.

On the development machine this runs like a charm. All greens, no problem at all. Now I copy the package and the configuration file to the test environment. A basic version without the file removing was running perfectly fine here. I replaced the package. Nothing big.

Now I run the SQl Server Agent Job and it starts running. I can see all the text files appearing, and disappearing after it created the zipfiles. However, when all files are removed the package results with errors. Namely the error shown above in the title.

- I tried looking for the connectionmanager that might have been removed
- Looked for connection managers named in the config that don't exist in the package.

No such thing found. Annoying part is that the package is fully functioning, but still results with the error.

**EDIT**: I noticed that if I run the package using the execute package utility with the dev. config it gives the same errors.

Hopefully someone is able to help me out. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you change the DelayValidation property on the `File System Task` to True, and run with no .txt files out there, does it still fail?

Comment: This didn't make a difference. I found out that if I disabled the File System Task with the delete operation the error stays away and the Agent Job runs succesfully. 

The File System Task uses the variable, that is set within the foreach loop, as a source. Any idea's?

Comment: Given your resolution (delete the task and re-add it), I wonder if there wasn't an Expression on the Task that was referencing an invalid object.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to "fix" the issue. Remove the File System Component responsible for deleting the files. Then add it again and configure it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens if you accidentally change General parameters before changing the Operation parameter.  It holds the metadata to irrelevant parameters and upon execution says: "Wait, you defined this parameter but I don't need it, but I'm checking for it anyway, and it's not there!"

It's a bug for sure